# Node Js: Validate empty array using class validator

Tags: node.js, arrays, class-validator

How to check whether the array is empty or not using class-validator.
Given below is my structure. I want to check if **cartId** is empty or not.

```
{
   "cartId": []
}
```

Comment: You can use `@IsNotEmpty()`.

Comment: @IsNotEmpty() doesn't catch an empty array, because [] IS a non-empty value.  As the selected answer show,s you must use @ArrayNotEmpty()

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you want is `@ArrayNotEmpty()`.
You can find all built-in validators here: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-decorators

If you don't find - you can write your own validator: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-classes

Comment: Really close in name to `@IsNotEmpty()`. Could see that catching people

Answer (score 1):

To check if array is empty, you can use `@ArrayNotEmpty()`, like this:

```
@ArrayNotEmpty({ each: true })
cartId: [];
```